# R script do not write in sqlite db if I run the script in shiny

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

I have a function that do some calculation and write the result in a sqlite db. With a shiny application I see the result but if I look into the db I can not see it. Any suggestions?
txs

Just for example

```
my_function = function(){
sometings

sqlAddDataToTable(db.file, result, tab.name)
return(result)
}
```

where sqlAddDataToTable is a function that open db, append 'result' and close db

in shiny I have

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){

    X = reactive({ my_function() })
})
```

ps If I run the script with my_function, it works

Comment: Did you try `reactive({ my_function() })`?

Comment: Yes, it was a misprint

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `reactive`need to have a reactive input to initiate the function. Maybe something like:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
    myReactives <- reactiveValues(myDF = my_function())
    X = reactive({ myReactives$myDF })
})
```

`x()` Should now contain the data.

Comment: thank you jd, but this not solve my problem. I see the result on the web application. But the application doesn't save the result on the sqlite db.

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example.