# How can I prevent RMySQL errors and show to user in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I have a Shiny App that executes a query to a MySQL database like this example:

UI

```
textAreaInput("query")
```

SERVER

```
data <- reactive({
  df<-dbGetQuery(conection, input$query)
  return(df)
})
```

The problem is that when the user types a wrong syntax in the textAreaInput the Shiny App closes and the error is shown in the R Console.

What I want is to print that error in the app so the user can try again and write another query.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Letting users run queries is not secure. What could be done instead is let them enter a single parameter to the query, and sanitize it with e.g. `sqlInterpolate`. Recommended read: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sql-injections.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tryCatch`. Here is a complete example based on  @Fan Li's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463302/save-changes-to-sqlite-db-via-shiny)

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="sample.sqlite")
dbWriteTable(con, "test", data.frame(value1 = letters[1:4], value2 = letters[5:8]))
dbDisconnect(con)

library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    #select * from te fail
    #select * from test work
    textAreaInput("query",'Query'),
    actionButton("action", label = "Run Query"),
    hr(),
    tableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    #Reactive is eager by definition and it will signal unreal/annoying errors, hence I used eventReactive
    data <- eventReactive(input$action,{
      tryCatch({
        con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="sample.sqlite")
        data<-dbGetQuery(con, input$query)
        dbDisconnect(con)
        return(data)
        }, 
               error = function(e){
                 showModal(
                   modalDialog(
                     title = "Error Occurred",
                     tags$i("Please enter valid query and try again"),br(),br(),
                     tags$b("Error:"),br(),
                     tags$code(e$message)
                   )
                 )
               })
    })
    output$table <- renderTable(data())
  }))
```