# Clear inputbox after entering value in SQLite

Tags: r, shiny

I found what I was looking for here: [Save changes to sqlite db via shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463302/save-changes-to-sqlite-db-via-shiny) but I want the two inputboxes "value1" and "value2" to clear its entries after the value is saved in the SQLite table by pushing the action button. I have tried       `updateTextInput(session, "value1", "value 1", NA)` but is being ignored. Could someone show me how to clear entries? Thanks

```
    library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)

#runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    textInput("value1", label = "Value 1"),
    textInput("value2", label = "Value 2"),
    actionButton("action", label = "Write to DB"),
    hr(),
    tableOutput("table")
  )
  
  
  server = function(input, output,session){
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      stopApp()
    }) 
    
    data <- eventReactive(input$action, {
      con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="sample.sqlite")
      dbWriteTable(con, "test", data.frame(value1 = input$value1, value2 = input$value2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), append = TRUE)
      data <- dbReadTable(con, "test")
      dbDisconnect(con)
      return(data)
      updateTextInput(session, "value1", "value 1", NA) #This is not updating the first box
    })
    output$table <- renderTable(data())
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) # ,options = list(height = 1080)
```

Comment: There is no notion of NA in HTML. What if you tried setting it to an empty string instead like `updateTextInput(session, "value1", value="")`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried `value=""` but it is ignored as well.

Comment: Oh, you have the `updateTextInput()` **after** your `return()`. When you run `return`, no other statements after that are run. R will exit the function immediately. Make sure to move that to before the `return()`